# Checking whether a host has a second-level domain from a list

Tags: python

I have an `url` and need to check whether it has some second-level domain (SLD) from a list. For example for SLD `foo.com` I need to approve hosts `foo.com`, `some.foo.com` and reject host `kungfoo.com`. There is some solution:

```
domains_a = ['foo.com', 'bar.com', 'fur.net', 'beer.org']
domains_dot_a = ['.foo.com', '.bar.com', '.fur.net', '.beer.org']

domains_b = ['door.com', ... ]
domains_dot_b = ['.door.com', ... ]

domains_c = ['doom.com', ... ]
domains_dot_c = ['.doom.com', ... ]

def any_sld_matches(domains, domains_dot, host):
    return (host in domains) or any(host.endswith(sld) for sld in domains_dot)

def get_url_category(url):
    host = urlparse.urlparse(url.strip()).netloc
    if any_sld_matches(domains_a, domains_dot_a, host):
        return 'a'
    elif any_sld_matches(domains_b, domains_dot_b, host):
        return 'b'
    elif any_sld_matches(domains_c, domains_dot_c, host):
        return 'c'
    elif not host:
        return 'empty'
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: We can't review this, there are essential parts of the code missing.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243). Please consider adding the sections of code which are replaced by the ellipses in your question.

Comment: Have you tested this code? It does not work as you intend. "I need to approve hosts `foo.com`, `some.foo.com` and reject host `kungfoo.com`". `any_sld_matches(['foo.com'], ['.foo.com'], 'kungfoo.com')` returns `True` after fixing the syntax error.

Comment: A lot of your questions tend to be redacted in weird ways that go against the spirit of Code Review. This code excerpt is actually broken, which makes it in fact off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your function to be much faster if you use a set.
You can also use `re` to reduce the amount of code too.

The regex that you can use is an optional non-capturing group of anything ending with a  `.`.
And a capturing group at the end of the string with one period:

```
(?=.+\.)?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
```

Using this you can lop off the second-level domain, and do a single check.

```
def get_url_category(url):
    host = urlparse.urlparse(url.strip()).netloc
    domain = re.search(r'(?=.+\.)?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$', host)
    if domain is not None:
        domain = domain.group(1)
        if domain in domains_a:
            return 'a'
    if not host:
        return 'empty'
    return None
```

To make this faster you should change `domains_a` to a set:

```
domains_a = {'foo.com', 'bar.com', 'fur.net', 'beer.org'}
```

And finally to make the program easier to write you can change the domains to be a dictionary of sets.
To use this just loop through the items via `domains.iteritems()`.
And if the host is found then you return the group.

```
domains = {
    'a': {'foo.com', 'bar.com', 'fur.net', 'beer.org'},
    'b': {'door.com', ...},
    'c': {'doom.com', ...}
}

def get_url_category(url):
    host = urlparse.urlparse(url.strip()).netloc
    domain = re.search(r'(?=.+\.)?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$', host)
    if domain is not None:
        domain = domain.group(1)
        for group, domains_ in domains.iteritems():
            if domain in domains_:
                return group
    if not host:
        return 'empty'
    return None
```

Finally I think returning None is a bit strange, but is fine.

Comment: Thank you (+1) Great solution! I heard opinion that regexp is pretty slow instrument.  Is it possible to be a problem?

Comment: @Loom Thanks for the edit! It's about 5 times slower than using `string.rfind`, I think using `string.rfind` is quite a bit more ugly then `re` which is why I chose `re`, if you think ~`0.0006` seconds per host is far too slow then I'd upload an ugly way to do it.
I timed it via `>>> import timeit; timeit.timeit("import re;host='sub.foo.com';re.search(r'(?=.+\.)?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$', host)")`